# How to close date picker window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal, daterangepicker

We have made a custom date box component with using Bootstrap. But we are unable to close the calendar date picker when we are on select  the date then the calendar in not close.

Anyone here tell me how to resolve this issue. Actually we have not good command in JS.

Here is [bootstrap-datetimepicker.js](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker).

**Intialization code:**

```
init = function() {

  var icon = false, i, dDate;
  picker.options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
  if (!(picker.options.pickTime || picker.options.pickDate))
    throw new Error('Must choose at least one picker');

  picker.id = dpgId++;
  moment.lang(picker.options.language);
  picker.date = moment();
  picker.element = $(element);
  picker.unset = false;
  picker.isInput = picker.element.is('input');
  picker.component = false;

  if (picker.element.hasClass('input-group'))
    picker.component = picker.element.find('.input-group-addon');

  picker.format = picker.options.format;
  if (!picker.format) {
    if (picker.isInput)
      picker.format = picker.element.data('format');
    else
      picker.format = picker.element.find('input').data('format');
    if (!picker.format)
      picker.format = (picker.options.pickDate ? 'L' : '');
    picker.format += (picker.options.pickTime ? ' LT' : '');
  }

  if (picker.component)
    icon = picker.component.find('span');

  if (picker.options.pickTime) {
    if (icon && icon.length) {
      picker.timeIcon = icon.data('time-icon');
      picker.upIcon = icon.data('up-icon');
      picker.downIcon = icon.data('down-icon');
    }
    /*  if (!picker.timeIcon)
                        picker.timeIcon = 'glyphicon glyphicon-time';*/
    if (!picker.upIcon)
      picker.upIcon = 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up';
    if (!picker.downIcon)
      picker.downIcon = 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down';
    if (icon)
      icon.addClass(picker.timeIcon);
  }
  if (picker.options.pickDate) {
    if (icon && icon.length)
      picker.dateIcon = icon.data('date-icon');
    if (!picker.dateIcon)
      picker.dateIcon = 'glyphicon glyphicon-calendar';
    if (icon) {
      icon.removeClass(picker.timeIcon);
      icon.addClass(picker.dateIcon);
    }
  }

  picker.widget = $(
    getTemplate(picker.timeIcon, picker.upIcon,
                picker.downIcon, picker.options.pickDate,
                picker.options.pickTime, picker.options.collapse))
  .appendTo('body');
  picker.minViewMode = picker.options.minViewMode
  || picker.element.data('date-minviewmode') || 0;
  if (typeof picker.minViewMode === 'string') {
    switch (picker.minViewMode) {
      case 'months':
        picker.minViewMode = 1;
        break;
      case 'years':
        picker.minViewMode = 2;
        break;
      default:
        picker.minViewMode = 0;
        break;
    }
  }
  picker.viewMode = picker.options.viewMode
  || picker.element.data('date-viewmode') || 0;
  if (typeof picker.viewMode === 'string') {
    switch (picker.viewMode) {
      case 'months':
        picker.viewMode = 1;
        break;
      case 'years':
        picker.viewMode = 2;
        break;
      default:
        picker.viewMode = 0;
        break;
    }
  }

  for (i in picker.options.disabledDates) {
    dDate = picker.options.disabledDates[i];
    dDate = moment(dDate);
    // if this is not a valid date then set it to the startdate -1
    // day so it's disabled.
    if (!dDate.isValid)
      dDate = moment(startDate).subtract(1, "day").format("L");
    picker.options.disabledDates[i] = dDate.format("L");
  }

  picker.startViewMode = picker.viewMode;
  picker.setStartDate(picker.options.startDate
                      || picker.element.data('date-startdate'));
  picker.setEndDate(picker.options.endDate
                    || picker.element.data('date-enddate'));
  fillDow();
  fillMonths();
  fillHours();
  fillMinutes();
  update();
  showMode();
  attachDatePickerEvents();
  if (picker.options.defaultDate !== "")
    picker.setValue(picker.options.defaultDate);
}
```

Comment: include your relevant datepicker code, not the whole plugin source file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open the [website](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/) and **read it**, it clearly says:

> #### Hide the datepicker.
>
> ```
> .datepicker('hide')
> ```

A **screenshot** for you, if you have missed it:

[image]

I don't understand how you even missed it, even though if you don't have a command over JavaScript.

---

If this wasn't the right issue, kindly create a snippet and then demonstrate the issue so that we can solve it.

Comment: where i use this .datepicker('hide');

Comment: @Sitansu You initialize datepicker by using `$(element).datepicker()`, right? When you wanna hide it, please use: `$(element).datepicker("hide")`

Comment: stopEvent = function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
   e.preventDefault();
   $(document).datepicker("hide") ;
  }

Comment: @Sitansu Not the `$(document)`. It should be the text field id or something. Show me your initialization code?

Comment: @Sitansu See my above message.

Comment: @Sitansu I cannot see anything that uses the `datepicker` function.